# How root android 8.1 gtaxlwifi?

Tags: root-access, tablet

i wanna root my tablet, Samsung Galaxy Tab A. I tried enable bootloader using Adb & fastboot and later twrp and magisk, but i couldnt use Fastboot Commands, even with drivers. So, are there way to unlock bootloader with/without pc?

Note:
I am using Ubuntu at pc

I will be thankfull if u say method :)

Comment: https://topjohnwu.github.io/Magisk/install.html#instructions

Comment: @alecxs the section header mentioned "*If your Samsung device is NOT launched with Android 9.0 or higher, you are reading the wrong section.*" though.

Comment: @AndrewT. this warning is regarding a-only system-as-root with *magisk in recovery*, but unlocking bootloader and patching *AP_\*.tar.md5* still applies (I have done it for SM-T555 android 7) reason is *fstab* might located in *vendor* and *vbmeta* needs to be patched

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.